# `cargo` uses `x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld` even if `linker=lld-link` is specified

Tags: rust, github-actions, rust-cargo, lld

I'm trying to build a UEFI binary in stable Rust, so I don't use the `x86_64-unknown-uefi` target as it requires the Nightly toolchain. To do so, I created `.cargo/config.toml`:

```
[build]
target = "x86_64-pc-windows-gnu"

[target.x86_64-pc-windows-gnu]
rustflags = [
    "-C", "link-args=/nologo /nxcompat /nodefaultlib /entry:efi_main /subsystem:efi_application",
    "-C", "code-model=large",
    "-C", "prefer-dynamic=n",
    "-C", "no-redzone=y",
    "-C", "panic=abort",
    "-C", "linker=lld-link",
]
```

Building succeeds on my local machine but fails on GitHub Actions ([log](https://github.com/toku-sa-n/antei/runs/2515237195)). The `x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld` is still used even if I specify `lld-link` as a linker.

How do I force `cargo` to use `lld-link`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `linker = "lld-link"` under the `[target.x86_64-pc-windows-gnu]` table?
Alternatively, try `CARGO_TARGET_X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_GNU_LINKER="lld-link" cargo build`. This should force its use throughout the dependency chain.